# Getting unique ID from iPhone NFC

Tags: ios, nfc, applepay

I have a device with an NFC reader that reacts differently when different people's phones are tapped on it. On Android this works fine, but iOS doesn't expose any NFC APIs - it is only used for Apple Pay.

My question is, a) do iPhone's send a unique ID with Apple Pay, and if so, b) can I have my NFC reader pretend to be an Apple Pay terminal *enough* that it can get that ID?

Highly hacky and speculative I know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a) do iPhone's send a unique ID with Apple Pay**

no it does not.

But It's possible to have an AID from the apple pay when is in contact with a NFC reader but it's just a random AID.